# QDialog always on top of parent

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have a non-modal QDialog that always appears on top of its parent. In this case the dialog doesn't have to have a parent, but then it shows in the taskbar. I haven't found the right set of options that allow the parent to be on top of the dialog and the dialog not show up in the taskbar. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, but depends on your window manager following the hint to group taskbar items

```
w = QtGui.QMainWindow(None)
w.setWindowTitle("Window")
w.show()
d = QtGui.QWidget(w, QtCore.Qt.Window )
d.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
d.show()
```